# Facebook Send button is not showing and comments dialog flickers

Tags: facebook, integration

I use Facebook on many pages but on this particular one I don't see Send button and when I click Like the comment dialog just flickers.

https://www.customerelite.com/lrm/ms/oid/587153

Does anybody see what's wrong with Facebook buttons on this page?

Thanks.

Comment: Dude, you need to elaborate more on your **"this particular one"**

Comment: It depends upon the query you are using. Why not use a simple code that FB itself provides?

`<div class="fb-like" data-href="YOUR FB Page" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="100" data-show-faces="true" data-font="segoe ui"></div>`

Comment: I added your code snippet right under the headline of the site and it's having the same problem.

Comment: However, I created a copy of the web page from my original post and changed the data-href setting in your code to point to my domain name and Like is working now, but Likes my domain and not the web page: https://www.customerelite.com/lrm/ms/oid/594934
The question remains why Facebook Like is not working on the site in my original post?

Comment: FB likes work corresponding to an app or a page in Facebook. When a user will click on the Like button in your site; the like will be added to a Facebook app or page. It depends how you design that particular app or page inside facebook.

Comment: I already have an app registered on Facebook. And FB integration works fine on most of my web pages. I added app_id on https://www.customerelite.com/lrm/ms/oid/594934 and FB Like is still not working.

Comment: It works fine on my system. However, as your buttons are inside `#container`; you don't see the "Send" button as the `#container`'s height restricts it.

Comment: I could swear that comments were flickering on this site just a minute ago. So, now I added app_id to the page in the OP and it's still having the same problem: https://www.customerelite.com/lrm/ms/oid/587153
I even rescraped it with Facebook Lint tool. Do you see the problem I am reporting?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13329/discussion-between-alecswan-and-ecko)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a Facebook bug. I filed a bug here https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/391962640871463